# How to get data from console using Unit Test Project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using **Selenium** `WebDriver` for `C#` and want to get **username** and **password** from `console`. My code is:

```
var username = Console.ReadLine(); 
var password = Console.ReadLine();

// open application
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://myurl");

// enter username and password, press enter
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Username")).SendKeys(username);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys(password);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

But `Console.ReadLine()` not working in Unit Test Project.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Is it a console application? If so, there's no reason that shouldn't work

Comment: No, it's Unit Test Project

Comment: It's not in general a good idea to collect data from the user interactively during a unit test.  You could use environment variables or a config file.

Comment: @jlew, I want testing application with different username and password. And it's difficult for me change everytime username and password from variable.

Comment: @diiN_, it's not working for me

Comment: @VaqifRV, what you mean "it's difficult for me change everytime username and password from variable"? You can use arrays and loops to change variable's value automatically...

Comment: your question not about selenium. its about using console in unit test project.

Comment: @Andersson, when I test app different username, I must change username variable from method. But I want read username from console.

Comment: @LeonBarkan, I call test method from console and pass username from console. Thanks everyone for answer.